# Python client for elasticsearch 8.5

Tags: python, authentication, elasticsearch, permissions, deprecated

I used to connect elasticsearch 7 self managed cluster using following code.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch,RequestsHttpConnection

es = Elasticsearch(['hostname'], timeout=1000,http_auth=('user_name', 'password'),use_ssl=True,verify_certs=True,connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,scheme="https",port=9200)
```

After updating the Elasticsearch to 8.5 most of the parameters were invalid. Need a help to figure out the correct way to connect elastic cluster in elastic search 8.5.

Answer (score 1):

In Elasticsearch 8.X, there have been [significant changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/release-highlights.html#_7_x_rest_api_compatibility) in the Elasticsearch API.

Now, in the Elasticsearch 8.X, the `scheme` and `port` need to be included explicitly as part of the hostname, `scheme://hostname:port` e.g.(https://localhost:9200)

The `http_auth` should be updated to `basic_auth` instead. You can have a look at all the [additional available options here](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.5.0/api.html#module-elasticsearch). So the new snippet to connect would be something like -

```
es = Elasticsearch(['https://hostname:port'], timeout=1000 ,basic_auth=('user_name', 'password'),verify_certs=True)
```

There are significant changes in the requests/responses while doing querying as well, so I would suggest giving [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/migration.html) a read.

---

If you are doing migration to elasticsearch 8.X from 7.X, for short-term, there is another workaround as well which would not require any code changes and just setting the `ELASTIC_CLIENT_APIVERSIONING=1` env variable in your python application.

> **Enable compatibility mode and upgrade Elasticsearch**
>
> Upgrade your Elasticsearch client to 7.16:
>
> `$ python -m pip install --upgrade 'elasticsearch>=7.16,<8`
>
> If you have an existing application enable the compatibility mode by setting `ELASTIC_CLIENT_APIVERSIONING=1` environment variable. This will instruct the Elasticsearch server to accept and respond with 7.x-compatibile requests and responses.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/migration.html#migration-compat-mode